# How do I install the Google Wave server software?

Tags: package-management

Now that the news is all around that [Google will stop Wave development](http://techcrunch.com/2010/08/04/wave-goodbye-to-google-wave/), and I like to keep using it, I was wondering how I can install their software. For example, is there a .deb package?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure :)

Answer (score 3):

DJango version? http://code.google.com/p/pygowave-server/

Java: code.google.com/p/wave-protocol/wiki/Installation

Comment: So, no .deb then?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some progress being made by the Google Team towards "Wave in a Box". The latest seems to be : https://groups.google.com/group/wave-protocol/browse_thread/thread/99434acbce5d807d